# CUDA Programming adding vectors in parallel is much slower(not faster)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda

I am a beginner in CUDA programming. I am trying to measure how efficient adding vectors in parallel is. However, I've realized that it's actually much slower than adding vectors not in parallel, which is the opposite of what I expected. I do not understand why this happens. Adding in parallel took 2904763 nano seconds and not adding in parallel took only 340 nano seconds. Please explain why.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>
cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size);

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}

// randomize array with random numbers 
void randomizeArr(int arr[],  int size) {

    unsigned int randNum;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        randNum = rand() % 100 + 1;
        arr[i] = randNum;
    }
}

void addWithCPU(int c[], int a[], int b[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int arSize = 100;
    int a[arSize] = { 0 };
    int b[arSize] = { 0 };
    randomizeArr(a, arSize);
    randomizeArr(b, arSize);
    int c[arSize] = { 0 };
    int d[arSize] = { 0 };

    // Add vectors in parallel.
    int iterations = 100;
    cudaError cudaStatus;
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        cudaStatus = addWithCuda(c, a, b, arSize);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin).count();
    std::cout << "Parallel : " << duration / iterations << "ns." << std::endl;

    // Add vectors NOT in parallel.
    auto begin2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        addWithCPU(d, a, b, arSize);
    }
    auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end2 - begin2).count();
    std::cout << "Not Parallel : " << duration2 / iterations << "ns." << std::endl;


    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!");
        fprintf( stderr ,"HERREEEE");
        std::getchar();
        return 1;
    }


    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }
    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size)
{
    int *dev_a = 0;
    int *dev_b = 0;
    int *dev_c = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    addKernel<<<1, size>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }

    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small set of value you will be slower because :

1. you need you copy your buffer on the device memory
2. you need to perform the computations
3. you need to copy the device buffer back on the host memory

Copying the data to device and back to the host are very costful operations. If you test your code on a much larger dataset, you should have a much larger increase factor of performance.

Try with 100 000 numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge. The maximum number I can try is 1000. If I go beyond that, for example, 1100, I get "addKernel launch failed invalid configuration argument". I know it's a differne question but do you know why this happens as well?

Comment: Yes, when you are tuning your kernell call <<<1, size>>> , you are telling the cuda runtime to just use one block and n threads. CUDA is limited to 512 threads per block. So you should have something of the form <<<numBlocks, numThreadsPerBlock>>>

Comment: By the way, you should check the examples provided with CUDA. if you are running on linux, you will find the vector sum at ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples/0_Simple/vectorAdd/ (replace 7.5 by your cuda version)

Comment: Just to add: CUDA is not generally limited to 512 threads per block. It is hardware dependent. Newer Nvidia gpus have a limit of 1024. (This is the case for the OPs hardware.)

Comment: @Shadow Thank you so much. You've just answered my 2nd question I was going to ask!.

Comment: Another point is that you won't really be faster with 100 000 number or any array size in fact. Adding two vectors is a memory bound problem and on CPU it will be limited by the RAM bandwidth, while the GPU code will be limited by the PCI bus bandwidth, which is typically a lot lower